# Mongo Query of Record by Array Object Field Value Using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have collection called 'jobs' with a document :

```
{
"_id": "4bb131682d0682845098eabe",
"jobId": "1403610",
"refmdList": [
    {
        "_id": "4bb11af1f8d48284e0b2ef87",
        "addrIdx": 1,
        "type": "primary"
    }
],
"status": "Created in J4",
}
```

And java code is used to find that job document using:

```
private DBCursor getRefMdCursor(String refId)
{
    DB db = JDatabase.getDatabase();
    BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject();
    search.put("refmdList._id", refId);

    DBCollection col = db.getCollection("jobs");
    DBCursor cur = col.find(search);
    return cur;
}
```

This is very slow and the refmdList._id is not indexed. Is the solution to index this array object field to speed it up or is there something problematic with the DBCursor code above?

DBCursor class is from mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.3/mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar

Comment: How many records matches this query? Did you try [.toArray()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) method?

Answer (score 0):

An array's sub-document field can be indexed, and these indexes are called a Multikey indexes. See [Index Arrays with Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents).

The field `refmdList._id` can be indexed. It can improve the performance of queries using that field as filter criteria.

*About the Java code:*

The *MongoDB Java driver* you are using is of older version (3.4.3), and there is a latest version available (3.12.0). Also, the Java code can be changed to use the newer APIs; see examples at [Find Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/).

Comment: Thanks for that info, that's helpful. The number of records in the collection is about 6 million so I would think this would make a difference. You agree? As for MongoDB Java driver, I'm not sure if an update to latest version would benefit the specific problem but thanks for the info. We may implement that as well.

Comment: Indexing will definitely help in improving the query performance. Run an `explain` with "executionStats" mode for the query and verify the _query plan_ - this will confirm that the index is being used. In fact run the query plan before and after indexing and verify the differences. Could you tell what version of MongoDB you are working with?

Comment: The cluster indicates version 3.6.16 it seems. I currently don't have access to changing this in our production environment as it was directed to investigate before it is changed. The most I could do now is query with explain using current.